# If $S$ is generated by $S_1$ as $S_0$-algebra, then $R=\oplus_{n\geq 0} S_{dn}$ (for fixed $d>0$) is generated by $S_d$ as $S_0$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $S=\oplus_{n\geq 0}S_n$ be a graded ring. If $S$ is generated by $S_1$ as an $S_0$-algebra, then is it true that the subring $R=\oplus_{n\geq 0} S_{dn}$ (for fixed $d>0$) is generated by $S_d$ as an $S_0$-algebra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The proof is below.

**Notation:** Given a set $A \subset S$, denote by $S_0[A]$ the $S_0$-algebra generated by $A$.

---

Given: $S = S_0[S_1]$.
To show: $R = S_0[S_d]$.

It is clear that $S_0[S_d] \subset R$. We show the other inclusion.

Clearly, $S_0 \subset S_0[S_d]$.
Fix $n > 0$ and let $s \in S_{nd}$ be arbitrary.

Then, there exists $k \ge 1$, a polynomial $f \in S_0[x_1, \ldots, x_k]$, and $s_1, \ldots, s_k \in S_1$ such that $$s = f(s_1, \ldots, s_k).$$

Assuming $\deg f = N$, we can write $f$ as a sum $f = f_0 + \cdots + f_N$ where each $f_i \in S_0[x_1, \ldots, x_k]$ is an $S_0$-linear combination of monomials of degree $i$.
In particular, $f_i(s_1, \ldots, s_k) \in S_i$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}.$

But since $S = \bigoplus_{n \ge 0}S_n$ and $s \in S_{nd}$, we see that $N \ge nd$ and $$s = f_{nd}(s_1, \ldots, s_k).$$

Now, note that $f_{nd}$ is a finite sum of elements of the form $ax_1^{j_1} \cdots x_k^{j_k}$ where $a \in S_0$ and $j_1 + \cdots + j_k = nd$ with each $j_i \ge 0$.
Upon substitution, we see that the sum is of the form $as_1^{j_1}\cdots s_k^{j_k}$. Note that you can now group the elements so that product $s_1^{j_1}\cdots s_k^{j_k}$ is of the form $t_1t_2 \cdots t_n$ where each $t_i$ is the product of $d$ elements of $S_1$ and thus, $t_i \in S_d$ for all $i$ and we have expressed $s$ as an element of $S_0[S_d]$ as desired.

Thus, $S_{nd} \subset S_0[S_d]$ for all $n \ge 0$ and we are done.

---

To elaborate more on the grouping, note that the product is

$$p = \underbrace{s_1 \cdots s_1}_{j_1} \cdot \underbrace{s_2 \cdots s_2}_{j_2} \cdot \cdots \underbrace{\cdot s_k \cdots s_k}_{j_k}.$$

There are a total of $nd$ many elements of $S_1$ above. Now, we can group the first $d$, then the next $d$ and so on, until we have $n$ groups of $d$ elements. Since $S$ is graded and each $s_i$ is in $S_1$, we see that the product of $d$ such elements is in $S_d$.

In particular, $ap \in S_0[S_d]$ since it equals the polynomial $ay_1\cdots y_n \in S_0[y_1, \ldots, y_n]$ evaluated at $(t_1, \ldots, t_n)$.